# X-axis action strange - Charts iOS

Tags: ios, swift, charts, tableview, ios-charts

I'm using the [Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) on iOS, but I'm having troubles with one of my charts in my TableView. The X-axis looks strange, and I loose resolution in my data. Here is how it currently looks:

[image]

My data is typically between 900 and 1100.

I configured the chart like this:

```
let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: "")
dataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
dataSet.lineWidth = 2
dataSet.mode = .horizontalBezier
dataSet.colors = UIColor.gray
dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false

let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])
self.chartEntries.append(lineChartData)
```

Any ideas on why my X-axis looks like this? My others charts look fine and dandy.

Comment: Can you show me your data or where r u assigning those data in chart ?

Answer (score 0):

The chart looks fine, since it's trying to squeeze your data that's around value 1000 into a very small space. If you have a look at the [MPAndroidChart lib wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis), you can see that you can adjust the min and max range per axis, so you can effectively zoom in closer to your values to better see the distribution:

> setAxisMaximum(float max): Set a custom maximum value for this axis.
>   If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on
>   the provided data.
>
> setAxisMinimum(float min): Set a custom minimum value for this axis.
>   If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on
>   the provided data.

It would look something like:

```
graph.yAxis.axisMinimum = 900
graph.yAxis.axisMaximum = 1100
```

Comment: Oh right. So I can just set the max to the highest datapoint + a constant, and min for the lowest datapoint + a constant to get the right zoom?

Comment: Oh, I can see I use a CombinedChart, and I dont seem to be able to access the axis' in the same manner?

Comment: I don't see why. Use a lineChart instead since you don't have any combined data.